# Vaadin 14 vs Vaadin 20 for brand-new project

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin20

I'm Java backend engineer  and would like to start the brand-new project. Unfortunately for me working with UI is some kind of nightmare :) This is why I'm looking for some framework which will abstract me from the low level JavaScript details and the best choice for now looks like is Vaadin Flow (pure Java).

Right now, I'm trying to select - what is the right version of Vaadin to start the project with - Vaadin 14 or recently released Vaadin 20? Please advise. Is it the right time to start with Vaadin 20?

Comment: There is no answer to your question, what is "best" for you or your project. There are no silver bullets. 14.X is the LTS branch and features from the higher versions get ported back to new 14.X+1 branches. Inform yourself what LTS means and what features are where. I have decided for myself, that i stick with 14.X and update to X+1 whenever possible in the hope, that the next LTS (somewhere around the lower 20ies) will be a smooth-ish transition. But this is partially JS-land and there are new breaking library/framework/upgrades paths every time you blink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends when you want to go to production with your application.

You can checkout the Vaadin roadmap to see when the releases are planned:
https://vaadin.com/roadmap

**Upcoming releases**

- Vaadin 14.7 LTS*, release date announced later
- Vaadin 21, estimated release September 2021
- Vaadin 22, estimated release December 2021
- Vaadin 23 LTS*, estimated release March 2022

If you want to go live next year I would go with Vaadin 20 otherwise with Vaadin 14.

In one project we are on Vaadin 20 already because the DataProvider changed in 19 and you don't need a CountCallback what is very handy if you want to use Grids with data from a REST API where you never have a count endpoint.